# How outdated are BGP books?

Tags: bgp, tcp, ip

I would like to learn more about BGP and there are many good books as I see but most of were made around 2000. How much did BGP change since then? I know that BGP and TCP/IP are the fundamentals but 15 years in the IT world seems like a thousand years.

Now I'm mostly interested in these books:

- BGP4 Case Studies/Tutorial - Sam Halabi
- Internet Routing Architectures, 2nd Edition - Sam Halabi
- Routing TCP/IP, Volume II - Jeff Doyle, Jennifer DeHaven Carroll

Comment: A few thing have been added since then (MP-BGP), but the operation is the same and those are excellent books to read and refer to.  But, sadly, questions like this are off-topic.

Comment: I don't believe the OP is asking for book recommendations, rather he has concerns over what has changed since they were published. As long as answers stick to what has changed in BGP and away from any book recommendations, I don't see any problem with this being on topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest change will be 32bit ASN's.

Another thing thats worth looking at is BGP security, especially RPKI, both RIPE and ARIN have good resources for them.

Answer (score 7):

A good way to find the differences is to look at the RFCs.

At the time a book published in 2000 was authored, the current version of BGP would have been according to the 1995 version of the standard: RFC1771.  Today the current version of BGP is described by RFC4271 published in 2005.

RFC4271 has a handy list of the changes since the previous version in Appendix A:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#appendix-A

(some of these changes were available as extensions before they were folded into the protocol update so the books may cover them or may not).

The top of the html version of the RFC also has a handy list of "updated by" references that you can use to find additional changes since 2005.

RFCs are written for implementors, so aren't necessarily the best way to learn how to *use* BGP; however they are the definitive reference for features so you can use them to identify what you want to learn about, and then use your google-fu to find more accessible documentation on that specific feature.